# Is it possible to get a tab (or window) identifier that stays the same across page reloads?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

### Question:

Is there an api or way to determine some kind of an id/uuid of the current tab/window the page is displayed in that is stable when the page is refreshed?

### To give you more context why this is important to me:

My use case is to allow my single page app (SPA) to be opened in multiple tabs at the same time.

Right now I can't do it because while the current state is persisted in a "currentModel" property in localStorage, unfortunately not all urls of the SPA are "self-contained" . By "self-contained" I mean that the url itself should be sufficient to reload that state from the backend (or localStorage) because it contains some kind of id/uuid (this flaw of my SPA has grown historically and I know it's not what HTML was meant to be used, however as there's a team of 60+ developers working on that SPA you can imagine that this cannot be refactored in a single day).

So what I have are some urls like this "/search" that display a search form, but also information about the current context (i.e. think business object).

Now if I want to allow the SPA to be opened simultaneously in multiple tabs, I can no longer use a simple "currentModel" property. Instead I need to make it a hashmap with the keys being tab/window ids so that the context of a tab can be restored in case the user hits F5/refresh in one of the tabs. Of course this id whatsoever would need to be stable across page reloads.

### Workarounds that I know of

1. Writing a custom browser extension that has access to tabs
2. Updating the url to include a "tab"-id created when the SPA is bootstrapped

Comment: Seems like the context is going to need to be in the URL, since that's all that's going to be sent to the server when the user hits F5. Everything else (cookies in particular) will be identical for all concurrent tabs.

Comment: There is, however, the window's "name" property. That seems to survive an F5 page reload. A new page won't have it of course, but you've got that problem already. So your code can maintain some navigational state in the name string, and then make use of it somehow from client-side code that's delivered in response to a GET from some URL on an existing tab.

Comment: @Pointy: window.name is exactly what I was looking for. Would you like to post this as an answer? I'd be happy to accept it as "the answer" to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.name` property (at least in modern Firefox and Chrome) maintains its value across an F5 page reload. Thus, code can check `window.name` for navigational hints or whatever else might be useful in order for it to "get its bearings" in the absence of information in the URL itself.

Thus, a newly-loaded tab will be able to detect that it is in fact newly loaded, and can insert and update the `name` property of the window whenever it wants. Upon a reload, code can sniff the `name` and request additional stuff from the server (or do whatever) if it sees that sort of information already present in the window name.

I have been able to put any sort of string into that property, in quite limited tests, but it's possible IE is picky about the name having to have some particular form (like a valid identifier or something).

Answer (score 1):

You may still be able to leverage `localStorage` but instead of keeping one object representing your state, maybe you should keep state on a route-by-route basis?

```
const state = {
  "/": { state: {} },
  "/page-2": { state: {} }
}
// persist state
localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state))
// unwrap state for route /
const routeState = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')))['/']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However your solution won't work in case that two tabs with different contexts happen to stay at the same url.

Comment: Hmm, then maybe in conjunction with Pointy's answer, you could use `window.name` to persist some sort of unique id per-window. Then use window.name as your state dictionary key, not route path.

Answer (score 1):

You can try leveraging the `window.onbeforeunload` action to save state for a page when a user refreshes the page. You could do something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    localStorage.setItem('lastState', JSON.stringify(state))
}
```

And then when a page reloads, check if state exists in localStorage, load it, and remove it. This method assumes that users won't be reloading pages and opening new ones at the same time. Otherwise, you'd need some other identifier when saving the state which puts you back in your original predicament.